# Wininet.dll crashes excel 64 bit when extracting cookies

Tags: excel, vba, wininet

my company moved from 32 bit excel to 64 and and now macros that used to pull cookies keeps crashing. I know about PtrSafe declaration, but this no longer works. K googled trying to find the correct declaration for it but can't seem to get it right. Maybe can someone point out where the LongLong or LongPtr needs to be used? Below code is my n-th try with no luck:

```
'clear current cookies
Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetSetOption Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetSetOptionA" (ByVal hInternet As Long, ByVal lOption As Long, ByVal sBuffer As String, ByVal lBufferLength As Long) As LongPtr
'retrieve cookie
Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetGetCookieEx Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetGetCookieExA" (ByVal pchURL As String, ByVal pchCookieName As String, ByVal pchCookieData As String, ByRef pcchCookieData As Integer, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal lpReserved As Integer) As Boolean

Private Const INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION = 42
Private Const INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY As Integer = &H2000
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call InternetSetOption(0, INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION, 0, 0)
    WebBrowser1.Silent = True
    'WebBrowser1.Navigate "salesforce.com"
    WebBrowser1.Navigate "salesforce.com"
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    If URL Like "*/home.jsp*" Then
        Call InternetGetCookieEx(URL, "sid", sessionId, 256, INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY, vbNull)
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where does your code crash? In `InternetGetCookieEx`? Where is `sessionId` declared and how is it initialized? I don't have excel 64 bit, so I can't try anything, but Ansi versions of API functions under 64-bit seem to be not the right one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to check the Microsoft documentation for these commands. When you are calling native methods like this you will find the [documentation is in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetsetoptiona) so we must do some translation.

We can also look at what [Microsoft says about LongPtr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/longptr-data-type).

> LongPtr is not a true data type because it transforms to a Long in
> 32-bit environments, or a LongLong in 64-bit environments. Using
> LongPtr enables writing portable code that can run in both 32-bit and
> 64-bit environments. Use LongPtr for pointers and handles.

In your case that will be at least the handle `hInternet` but I would also cover the buffer length to avoid overflow problems. I would also convert all Integers to Longs.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetSetOption Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetSetOptionA" (ByVal hInternet As LongPtr, ByVal lOption As Long, ByVal sBuffer As String, ByVal lBufferLength As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetGetCookieEx Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetGetCookieExA" (ByVal pchURL As String, ByVal pchCookieName As String, ByVal pchCookieData As String, ByRef pcchCookieData As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal lpReserved As LongPtr) As Boolean
```

**EDIT:** Let's also declare `lpReserved As LongPtr` because it starts with lp, which could mean Long Pointer.

ERRORS YOU MUST GUARD FROM:
To avoid unhandled exceptions in native code, check the exceptions that this command can throw and guard against them before calling in to native methods.

> Return code   Description
>
> ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS
>
> There is no cookie for the specified URL and all its parents.
>
> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER
>
> The value passed in lpdwSize is insufficient to copy all the cookie
> data. The value returned in lpdwSize is the size of the buffer
> necessary to get all the data.
>
> ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
>
> One or more of the parameters is invalid.
>
> The lpszUrl parameter is NULL.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer, I tried your declarations but it still crashed. I now have a feeling that this could be more than just declaration related

Comment: What line is it crashing on? Is there an error, or does Excel just close?

Comment: No error, excel just shuts down and thats it.

Comment: Yup, that's an unhandled exception in native code. I added a list of exceptions the get method can throw. Ensure they aren't true before you call the method.

Comment: Ensure you always have an error handler `On Error Goto ...` in these methods

Comment: Hi, how do I deal with these unhandled exceptions? Sorry Im not familiar with the process? Do I check the excel log after it crashes to see if one of those you mentioned is true?

Comment: No, I was suggesting that you need a VBA error handler. This won't save you from exceptions in native code. You're in C++ territory and VBA is not the best tool for the job.

Comment: So im guessing this is a dead-end then? Only solution would be to move back to 32 bit excel?

Comment: No. If you ensure that you never pass bad values to native code, it will work. Ultimately, you're writing code that relies on Internet Explorer. You should stop doing that altogether. VBA is not the best tool for this job. If you must use VBA, at least stop reinventing the wheel. Use a library: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web